# What is the difference between "He is onto something" and "He is up to something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is "**He is onto something**" an opposite of "**He is up to something**"?

Say, a man is married but he is chasing another woman without his wife's acknowledgement. This is a bad thing.

In this situation, do we say "**He is up to something**" because "**up to something**" often refers to something bad?

Now, a man is married but suspects his wife is cheating on him.

In that situation, do we say "**He is onto something**" because "**onto something**" often refers to something good or leading to a good result?

What is the difference between "**He is onto something**" and "**He is up to something**"?

Comment: Not a question of 'bad or good', just two different phrases. If you are 'onto something', you are having thoughts which may lead to a discovery (good, like a scientific advance, or bad, like the detection of a crime).

Comment: You can be up to something in a good way. Mother: Our son Jack has secretly baked a 10 foot tall cake for my birthday! Father: I knew he was up to something!

Comment: It's trivial to google [**define "be up to something"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22be+up+to+something%22&oq=define+%22be+up+to+something%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7570j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [**define "be onto something"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22be+onto+something%22&oq=define+%22be+onto+something%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6620j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Just because both usages can have a range of [non-overlapping] meanings doesn't justify asking here about the difference between them. They're certainly not "opposites".

Answer (score 1):

They're different and unrelated expressions. Neither is the opposite of the other.

The opposite of "*He's onto something*" is "*He's **not** onto **anything***".

The opposite of "*He's up to something*" is "*He's **not** up to **anything***".